# Removing lines from a query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
OrderID | OldOrderID    | Action    | EntryDate | Source 
    1   |     NULL      |   Insert  | 2016-01-12|   A
    1   |     NULL      |   Remove  | 2016-01-13|   A
    2   |     NULL      |   Insert  | 2016-01-12|   B
    3   |     NULL      |   Insert  | 2016-01-12|   C
    4   |       3       |   Insert  | 2016-01-13|   C
    4   |     NULL      |   Remove  | 2016-01-14|   C
```

I want to query all orders that are currently active orders - they dont have the action remove. Currently I do it with this query :

```
WITH Active AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID,Source ORDER BY EntryDate DESC)
  FROM Orders
)
SELECT *
FROM Active WHERE [Action] <> 'Remove' AND rn = 1;
```

The problem is that some orders get child orders (OrderID 3 gets a child OrderID 4) and if a child ever gets the Action Remove the query should also ignore the parent, but with the current query it dosent.

In short the current query gets me this result:

```
OrderID | OldOrderID    | Action    | EntryDate | Source 
    2   |     NULL      |   Insert  | 2016-01-12|   B
    3   |     NULL      |   Insert  | 2016-01-12|   C
```

But I need this result:

```
OrderID | OldOrderID    | Action    | EntryDate | Source 
    2   |     NULL      |   Insert  | 2016-01-12|   B
```

Is it possible to fix the query to get a result like this?

Comment: Can a child order have a child of its own?

Comment: Previously I said that a child can not have its own child wich is wrong, a child can have a child of its own, so if some where down the line a child is removed it should exclude all rows up to the first parent.

Comment: Also some rows have OldOrderID equal to 0 or OrderID instrad of null, when they have no children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked the question on dba stackexchange and got the following [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126221/81371), which works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT OrderID, OldOrderID, Action, EntryDate, Source,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'Remove' THEN 1 END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID) AS IsRemoved,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY EntryDate) AS rn
   FROM Orders  
)
SELECT c1.*
FROM CTE AS c1
LEFT JOIN CTE AS c2 ON c1.OrderID = c2.OldOrderID AND c2.IsRemoved >= 1
WHERE c1.rn = 1 AND c1.IsRemoved = 0 AND c2.IsRemoved IS NULL
```

The above query uses `COUNT() OVER()` in order to count the number of occurrences of `Action = 'Remove'` within each `OrderID` partition. Hence, a value of `IsRemoved` that is equal to or greater than 1 identifies a 'removed' order.

Comment: This query works just as intended. There is only one issue, which is my fault for poorly checking the data, a child can also have a child, so this query leaves the parent if a child down the road is removed.